# Create dynamic tooltips with tippy.js

Tags: javascript, tooltip, tippyjs

I create multiple tooltip contents with [tippy.js](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/) But i can't make dynamic content. It shows only first tooltip template.

Second problem is, when i put `style: display:none` to tooltip wrapper, tooltip doesn't shows. When i remove `style: display:none`, tooltips content showing as normal (it must be hidden).

How can i make tooltips with child template?

Also here is codepen example: https://codepen.io/wpuzman/pen/mQeeRQ

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.box').each(function(){
      tippy(this, {
          arrow: true,
          arrowType: 'round',
          size: 'large',
          duration: 500,
          animation: 'scale',
          placement: 'left',
          interactive: true,
          theme: 'google',
          content: document.querySelector('.tooltip_templates').cloneNode(true)
      });
  });
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  margin: 150px;
  position: relative;
}

.box {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@3/dist/tippy.all.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/50/50" alt="">

    <div class="tooltip_templates" style="display: none;">
      <div class="tooltip-content">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/150/150" alt="">
        <h3>Test image 1</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/50/50" alt="">

    <div class="tooltip_templates" style="display: none;">
      <div class="tooltip-content">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/150/150" alt="">
        <h3>Test image 2</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/50/50" alt="">

    <div class="tooltip_templates" style="display: none;">
      <div class="tooltip-content">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/150/150" alt="">
        <h3>Test image 3</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/50/50" alt="">

    <div class="tooltip_templates" style="display: none;">
      <div class="tooltip-content">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/150/150" alt="">
        <h3>Test image 4</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/50/50" alt="">

    <div class="tooltip_templates" style="display: none;">
      <div class="tooltip-content">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/150/150" alt="">
        <h3>Test image 5</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/50/50" alt="">

    <div class="tooltip_templates" style="display: none;">
      <div class="tooltip-content">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/150/150" alt="">
        <h3>Test image 6</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the current element to select its template:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.box').each(function(){
      tippy(this, {
          arrow: true,
          arrowType: 'round',
          size: 'large',
          duration: 500,
          animation: 'scale',
          placement: 'left',
          interactive: true,
          theme: 'google',
          content: this.querySelector('.tooltip_templates')
      });
  });
});
```

`this.querySelector('.tooltip_templates')` will select the child with that class which will be used as the content.

You can also avoid the `.each()` loop by using a function for the `content`:

```
tippy('.box', {
    animateFill: false,
    arrow: true,
    arrowType: 'round',
    size: 'large',
    duration: 500,
    animation: 'scale',
    placement: 'left',
    interactive: true,
    theme: 'google',
    content: function (reference) {
        return reference.querySelector('.tooltip_templates');
    }
});
```